# In Python Sympy, how would I declare two variables to be not equal positive integers?

Tags: python, sympy

I need to integrate a function in sympy.py, using two non-equal variables, n and m that are both positive integers.

I need some help please in understanding how to tell sympy that they cannot be equal, but can be all other positive integers besides each other.

Cheers in advance - Paul

Comment: Example needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you include some code, to have a better idea of what you are doing, but here's a guess anyway.

I think you can include this info in your function, and it should define m and n appropriately.

```
   n > 0 
   m > 0    #greater than zero
   m != n   #not equals
```

Comment: Executing any of these three statements has basically no effect (except wasting a few CPU cycles).

Comment: Thanks, that was truly helpful, in that you offered nothing of your own. I was thinking as a mathematician.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't withholding, I just wasn't sure it's possible to specify the constraints you want. Turns out you can. Sympy is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Let `m = Symbol('m', positive=True, integer=True)` and `n = m + Symbol('i', positive=True, integer=True)`. `n` and `m` are both positive and never equal (as guaranteed by use of the parameter `i`.